# Repairing a broken alsa

Tags: alsa, lubuntu

Can somebody give me the appropriate methodology in dealing with a broken alsa ? To be honest I don't know what happenned but that the computer went out of battery while sleeping (the pc not me), and then I was not able to get sound back up.
alsa-info allowed me to upload the [diagnostic](http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=950dc2b142499bcfdfecf6a4d4d57b2e3b8754bc). I'd like to point out the fact that I don't have any volume icon on my launcher anymore and I'm using Lubuntu. I tried purging and reinstalling alsa-base but with no effects. I don't want to reinstall the whole system because of that.

Comment: According to alsa-info, everything looks file. Does `aplay something.wav` work? Do you see anything when running `pavucontrol`?

Comment: I don't got a wav file but ogg starts and out puts no sound, as for pavucontrol it showed the rhythmbox app playing music and the sound level varying. But can't hear anything..

Answer (score 0):

Try to run alsamixer form command line.
Press f6 to see if you can select your soundcard form the list and adjust volumes.

Comment: I got either 'default' (which is selected by default...) or 'HDAIntel' (which must be the same), no sound, thank you guys for spending time to help me I guess my hardware is broken, that is just going to help me concentrate on my work lol

Comment: Did you adjust volumes, and unmute "Master"?

Comment: You can also try to boot some live distribution in order to test sound in it. This will isolate problem to either software issue or hardware failure.

Comment: I just read that, as I was pointing out I'm puzzled by the fact that I have no volume control, I might have uninstalled it but I don't know what would be the name of that program taht lets me control the volume from the desktop, I will try booting a live image. Very good advice

Answer (score 0):

So the froward truth is that my mute boutton only mutes, doesn't unmute. I needed to access the software's volume control, I guess you can do it in multiple ways, I installed 'pasystray' and I unmuted to the volume, works.